# When does $\overline{X \cap Y} = \overline{X} \cap \overline{Y}$ in $\mathbb P^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Say we have two algebraic sets, $X = V_{\mathbb A^2}(x+y-1)$ and $Y = V_{\mathbb A^2}(x^3+x^2y + y - 1)$.

Is it necessarily true that $\overline{X \cap Y} = \overline{X} \cap \overline{Y}$ for $\overline{X}$ indicating the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb P^2$? In general, is it true that for two algebraic sets is $\overline{X \cap Y} = \overline{X} \cap \overline{Y}$?

I'm also looking at how to determine the projective closure of algebraic sets, as I don't quite understand how to do so.

Comment: Are you using Zariski topology? In that case, $X$, $Y$, and $X\cap Y$ are closed, so the equality holds trivially.

Comment: @Ja_1941 yes i am using the Zariski topology. how exactly is the equality holding in this case? is it because the sets are discrete?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are already closed in Zariski topology and so is their intersection. So both sides are $X\cap Y$.